# open a menuitem page in a new tab in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs, menuitem

I have a xhtml page with a **session scoped** backing bean. Now i have to open this page in a new tab with right click open link in new tab.
When this page opens the model class of the backing bean must be cleared.
I have used the following code:

```
<p:menuitem value="Details" action="#{beanMB.clearDetailModel()}"/>
```

backing bean code:

```
public void clearDetailModel()
    {
        memberModel=null;
        ......
        return "/pages/member/MemberDetails.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
   }
```

The above code clears the session scoped model but it does not open the page in new tab.

Is there any method to open the page in new tab with the above code or is there any alternate way for the above problem?.Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It did not work, i need to open the page with right click - open link in new tab. The function clearDetailModel() is called only with direct left click but not with right click - open link in new tab.

Comment: What is the usecase? If you need to clear a **sessioscope**d model when opening a page in a new tab you have a design flaw. Either introduce a viewscoped bean or even a (cdi extention based) window scope

Comment: I have used session scope because i need to display an image in the form. Without session scope the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

You need to put the following code in MemberDetails.xhtml page.

```
<f:metadata>
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{beanMB.clearDetailModel}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

and use url in menuitem to open your page.

```
<p:menuitem value="Details"  url="/pages/member/MemberDetails.xhtml" />
```

you need to modify your backing bean code as follows:

```
public void clearDetailModel()
    {
        if (isNewRequest()){
        memberModel=null;
        ......
        }

   }

public boolean isNewRequest() {
        final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final boolean getMethod = ((HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getMethod().equals("GET");
        final boolean ajaxRequest = fc.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest();
        final boolean validationFailed = fc.isValidationFailed();
        return getMethod && !ajaxRequest && !validationFailed;
    }
```

Here method isNewRequest() checks if the request is new or not if this is not checked your method clearDetailModel() will be called each time new request is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute **`ajax="false"`** along with **`target="_blank"`** to the `p:menuitem`. It should look like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="Details" target="_blank" ajax="false" action="#{beanMB.clearDetailModel()}"/>
```